# Getting array/list element index

Tags: algorithm, erlang

I was trying to solve [this](https://leetcode.com/problems/two-sum/) little problem from LeetCode:

```
-module(two_sum).

-export([main/2]).

-spec main(List :: list(), Target :: non_neg_integer()) -> list().

%%%==================================================================
%%% Export
%%%==================================================================
main(List, Target) ->
  P = [{string:str(List, [X]), string:str(List, [Y]), X + Y} || X <- List, Y <- List, Y > X andalso X + Y =:= Target],
  io:format("Result: ~w~n", [P]).
%%[X + Y || X <- List, Y <- List, Y > X].
%%iterate(List, Target, 0, {}).

%%%==================================================================
%%% Internal
%%%==================================================================
iterate([], _Target, _Sum, _Result) -> {};
iterate([H | T], Target, Sum, Result) ->
  %%io:format("H >> ~w; T >> ~w, Target >> ~w~n", [H, T, Target]).
  Acc = Sum + H,
  case Acc =:= Target of
    true -> erlang:append_element(Result, H);
    false -> iterate(T, Target, Acc, Result)
  end.
```

My questions are:

1. Is there a more efficient way to get the element's index from an array/list? Currently I'm using this: `{string:str(List, [X])`, but I'm not sure if that's correct, although it gets the job done.
2. If I happen to get, for instance, a result like this: `R = [{1,2,9},{1,3,13},{1,4,17},{2,3,18},{2,4,22},{3,4,26}]`, how do I pattern match for `{1,2,9}`, knowing that `9` is `Target`? I tried `[{X1, X2, Target}] = R`...but it didn't like it!

Comment: If you describe the 'problem statement' in the question and explain your algorithm in a language agnostic pseudo-code, then there is a better chance for you to get a response (assuming your question is regarding the algorithm and not the specific language feature).

Comment: I don't get your questions. More efficient way from what? And BTW, I think your algorithm isn't actually working correctly.

Answer (score 1):

How about this. For each element, check its sum with each subsequent element in the list, carrying along the two indices, to be used to report to the user if a match is found.

```
find_indices(Target, [_H | T] = L) ->
  find_indices(Target, L, T, 0, 1).


find_indices(_Target, [_], [], _I, _J) ->
  io:format("No match~n");

find_indices(Target, [_Curr | LeftRest], [], I, _J) ->
  find_indices(Target, LeftRest, tl(LeftRest), I + 1, I + 2);

find_indices(Target, [Curr | _LeftRest], [Other | _RightRest], I, J)
  when Target =:= Curr + Other ->
  io:format("Match at indices ~p and ~p: ~p + ~p = ~p~n", 
    [I, J, Curr, Other, Target]),
  ok;

find_indices(Target, L, [_Other | RightRest], I, J) ->
  find_indices(Target, L, RightRest, I, J + 1).
```

Example:

```
1> index:find_indices(7, [1,2,3,4,5,6]). 
Match at indices 2 and 3: 3 + 4 = 7
ok
2> index:find_indices(11, [1,2,3,4,5,6]).
Match at indices 4 and 5: 5 + 6 = 11
ok
3> index:find_indices(12, [1,2,3,4,5,6]).
No match
ok
4> index:find_indices(4, [1,2,3,4,5,6]). 
Match at indices 0 and 2: 1 + 3 = 4
ok
```